# Combined address/search bar in firefox

Tags: firefox, search

For a long time on Windows and OSX, Firefox has had combined search and address bar without recourse to any addon. I am running Ubuntu and the search and address bar is separate and I can't find any option to do this in the preferences and about:config. Do I have to use an addon ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the search box. The address bar should have the same behavior (auto-search).

If it does not, you can try changing the [keyword.URL setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyword.URL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Foobar Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foobar/). It takes maximum 5 seconds and Firefox need to be restarted.

> Foobar integrates the functionality of the search bar into the address bar. This not only streamlines Firefox's appearance, but also makes search and navigation quicker and easier than ever.

Comment: `Foobar` has been deprecated; [Omnibar Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/omnibar-lite) takes it where Omnibar's developper stopped. On my FF 54 it is compatible with add-ons such as *Add to Search Bar* or *Location Bar Enhancer*.